# isn't non-type parameter pack that evaluates to "void..." illegal?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, void, variadic-templates

gcc-4.8 accepts this code, but isn't it wrong since the non-type parameter pack is equivalent to `void...` which is illegal?

```
template <typename T,
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type...>
void test(T) {}
```

I tried this with clang-3.5 as well which also accepts it. Is this a compiler bug, or am I misunderstanding something?

---

Full test code below, which uses non-type empty parameter packs to simplify enable_if.
This is almost the same as what's in [Flaming Dangerzone's Remastered enable_if](https://web.archive.org/web/20150726012736/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/almost-static-if/) except after substitution the pack becomes `void...`.

```
#include <type_traits>

template < typename C >
using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<C::value>::type ;

template < typename T, enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>>... >
void test(T){} // #1

template < typename T, enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>>... >
void test(T){} //#2

int main()
{
   test(0);   // calls #1
   test(0.0); // calls #2
   return 0;
}
```

gcc-4.8 compiles the above code just fine. clang doesn't but that's because it has a different bug http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=11723.

Comment: I think it is illegal. See paragraph [temp.param] 14.1/7 of the standard: "A non-type template-parameter shall not be declared to have floating point, class, or void type."

Comment: You should provide self contained code. All i can say is that as written your code does not compile because of missing includes and missing main.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb See [a simple example](http://ideone.com/hxuKmJ) which reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Constructor It seems that it's not checked unless it's used: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e60e1c9a202d3e0f

Comment: @dyp It is interesting. What do you think about it? Is this behavior legal?

Comment: @dyp you have another error because you pass a type to a non-type parameter (`void()` is a function type).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb True, I'm not sure how it's interpreted in that context (functional notation cast or type). Anyway, I think what it shows is that there is a check when the parameter pack is used (non-empty). So the question might be "are empty non-type parameter packs of type `void` legal?"

Comment: @dyp that doesn't matter in practice because even if they were, the rule "if all valid specializations require an empty template parameter pack, the template definition is ill-formed, NDR" would apply (and while there seem to be unintended rejections based on this rule, for example assertions like `require_empty_pack<T...>();`, I think the rejection of the questions' code based on this rule would be intended as it eases the job for the compiler).

Comment: (I must weaken my statement "that doesn't matter in practice", because the question in code has `T` be variable, so `test` can indeed be instantiated for non-empty packs aswell, so the rule would not apply to this particular code..)

Comment: I added a real test code, and explained how such empty packs can be used.

Comment: I think the code is fine.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in this code where you instantiate `test` with inputs resulting in `void...`.

Comment: `void...` isn't instantiated, but it's the result of substitution.

Comment: appears to be similar to `template<int N> void f(char[n]) { }`. some compilers do not reject `f<0>()` either because they transform `char[N]` to `char*` immediately and then there is no `N` left to substitute. In your case, there is no pattern left to substitute into.

Comment: Right, but is it legal according to the standard?

Answer (score 1):

After much searching in the context of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51787713/694509), I have found a bit in the standard that clearly states this is illegal:

[[temp.res]/6.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#general-6.3):

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if: ...
> every valid specialization of a variadic template requires an empty template parameter pack

So, the program is ill-formed, and compilers are not required to warn you about it.