# SFINAE fails to reject a type on GCC8.2, GCC7.1 is OK

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17

Could you confirm this is a regression in gcc?

#### Program

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class U, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_const_v<U>>...>
void f() {}

int main()
{
    f<const int>();
    f<int>();
}
```

#### Compilation

- `gcc7.1 -std=c++17`: *template substitution failed* on `f<int>`;
- `clang6.0 -std=c++17`: *no matching function for call to f* on `f<int>`;
- `gcc8.2 -std=c++17`: accepts the program.

#### Demo

https://godbolt.org/g/9vwsx1

---

Note: [`enable_if<...>::type...` is valid here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23401376/5470596).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51787713/5470596

Comment: That's quite an interesting way to apply SFINAE.

Comment: What's the difference from the related question you linked?

Comment: There's a huge difference: there's only one template function defined.